# How do I make different email accounts use the default sounds again?

Tags: ios, email, audio, mobile-mail

On an iPhone running iOS 6.0.1, I used Settings → Notifications → Mail to set different "new message" sounds for different mail accounts. Now I want to make all mail accounts again follow the default sound set under Settings → Sounds → New Mail. How can I do this? When I change the "New Mail" alert sound, the individual mail accounts no longer change.

I have tried manually setting all the mail accounts to use the same sound and vibration setting as the default. However, they still don't change when I change the default setting.

Comment: does the issue still persists after the 6.1 update?

Comment: @Macmaniman Yes. There's no UI element I can find that would "follow default settings", so as far as I can tell each mail account is "follow the default settings until I customize it once, then never again".

Comment: For some dumb reason i cant figure out how to comment so please someone tell me, considering your problem still persists, i recommend, iCloud backup/restore. however, the problem might persist, sense its a "setting" its worth a try!

Comment: @Macmaniman It's not worth it to me to go through that much trouble. An easier solution would probably be to delete then re-add the mail account. But, I also don't want to bother with that. It's just odd that there doesn't seem to be a setting for this.

Comment: it is, you are right, but, its really not touble, i think its suuuper easy, however, you are absolutly right its wierd that you cant reset the setting!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct answer, but by deleting an App, you remove the local cached copy of the emails and don't lose any messages on the Mail server.

This has a side effect of clearing the preference for sounds, so when you add the account back - it now follows the default sounds as set in the UI.